# Matlab - combining date and time columns in excel

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a csv file that contains two columns `date` and `time` as follows

```
date        time    
2015-01-08  11:15:29
2015-01-08  11:15:56
2015-01-08  11:16:28
2015-01-08  11:16:38
2015-01-08  11:16:38
```

I have imported the csv file into matlab.Is there a way to combine there two values so as to plot a time series.

I want `2015-01-09 11:15:20` to come after `2015-01-08 11:15:29`

Answer (score 0):

You mention excel in the title, so here's a method **using excel**.

*I changed the times a little to demonstrate that excel can sort the times.*

Starting point:

> ```
> 1/8/2015  11:16:28
> 1/8/2015  11:16:38
> 1/8/2015  11:16:48
> 2/8/2015  11:15:29
> 2/8/2015  11:16:28
> 3/8/2015  11:15:56
> ```

You can take your two columns and add a third column that just adds the two together. Go into the column to the right of your top-right data cell and type:

```
=[date cell ID]+[time cell ID]
```

Replace the contents of the "date/time cell ID" with the actual cells by clicking on them.

Result:

> ```
> 1/8/2015  11:16:28    1/8/2015 11:16
> 1/8/2015  11:16:38    
> 1/8/2015  11:16:48    
> 2/8/2015  11:15:29    
> 2/8/2015  11:16:28    
> 3/8/2015  11:15:56
> ```

Then click on your newly edited cell, and drag the bottom-right corner down to the bottom row of your data.

Result:

> ```
> date        time    
> 1/8/2015  11:16:28    1/8/2015 11:16
> 1/8/2015  11:16:38    1/8/2015 11:16
> 1/8/2015  11:16:48    1/8/2015 11:16
> 2/8/2015  11:15:29    2/8/2015 11:15
> 2/8/2015  11:16:28    2/8/2015 11:16
> 3/8/2015  11:15:56    3/8/2015 11:15
> ```

Now you have a variety of paths to plot the data. If you want to plot in excel, just click-drag over your new column and other data (if applicable) and excel will plot the data without the need to sort it.